# Bash : how to rename files that have two extentions?

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I call a small program to convert .tap files (retrogaming) into .wav audio files. The program output the new file and just add the .wav extention
example : "file.tap" becomes "file.tap.wav".

I wrote a tiny script to batch the conversion. It works but I cannot manage to rename the file at the end so to remove the ".tap" in the filename.
Note that sometime the original file has lowercase or uppercase.

here is my code. Any help is welcome.
My idea was to 'erase' the ".tap" or ".TAP" in the final filename.
nb : I must use $file.wav like that in the instruction, otherwise it doesn't work.
thank you for your help

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `ls`;
do
    ./tape_converter -11 -a $file $file.wav ;
    mv $file ${file/\.tap\.wav/\.wav/};

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your script to something like

```
for f in *.tap; do
    <your command> "$f" "${f%.*}.wav"
done
```

this will name directly the output files with same basename and extension ".wav".

Comment: it is indeed part of the solution. At the end it works; that's the important point .

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.tap`, then add `.wav`; there's no need for trying to do a replacement.

```
for f in *; do
   ./tape_converter -11 -a "$f" "$f.wav"
   mv -- "$f" "${f%.tap}.wav"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't remove .tap

Comment: This doesn't remove ".tap" in the final files, but removes it from the original files (which have .tap as extension)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code. Thanks to 
thanasisp. It works fine. Happy.

```
 for i in *;
    do mv "$i" "$(echo $i|tr A-Z a-z)";
 done

 mkdir output

 for f in *.tap;
 do
         ./tape_converter -11 -a $f ${f%.*}.wav ;
         mv *.wav output/
 done
```